# positioning of submit button on html form

Tags: html, forms, email

I am trying to figure out how to position the "submit" button on a simple html email submission form to the right of the submission field, rather than below the field. This form is going to hook up to my Mailchimp email list, such that when someone enters their email, it immediately gets added to Mailchimp. Here's what I have so far. Really appreciate the help.

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css"       rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this  style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your     HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://buzzpoint.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post? u=dc0ba2324b61f63ec1128f785&amp;id=126599f6a4" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div class="mc-field-group">
<label for="mce-EMAIL"> <span class="asterisk"></span>
</label>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>  <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 5):

Wait a minute... Is this to go into a html email?

If so you definitely need to consider rewriting the html into tables to make it work across most clients (Check in Outlook 07 if you don't believe me).

Also any form will not work in a html email because of the blocks in place to protect end users. Please consider changing this to be a link like "Sign up to FooBar now." and then have your form on a webpage. At the very best you will get a minuscule form completion rate because users are not used to completing forms inside the emails themselves.

In terms of your original issue you can try using `float` and `margin-right` css properties to position the button accordingly. Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srqsn/).

```
<input style="float:right; margin-right:12px;" type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
```

Comment: First, thanks so much for the help! To clarify, this form is going to be embedded on our website to collect emails. Given that, can you clarify for me where in the code I pasted above the float and margin-right css properties should be implemented?

Comment: @JeffEvans There is a jsfiddle link on my answer which may help you. The float and margin to your submit button with id "mc-embedded-subscribe".

Comment: thanks again. The tricky thing that I haven't been able to figure out is how I get the button right next to the form (on the right). With the code you provided, unless I am mistaken, it looks like the button is still below the field. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css"       rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
  #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
  /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this  style block.
     We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your     HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup" style="position: relative;">
  <form action="http://buzzpoint.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post? u=dc0ba2324b61f63ec1128f785&amp;id=126599f6a4" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
      <label for="mce-EMAIL"> <span class="asterisk"></span>
      </label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" style="width: 80%;">
        <input style="width: 15%; float: right; margin-top: -32px;" type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
      </div>
      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>  
      <div class="clear">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This assumes you don't care about maintaining a width (along with a host of other aesthetic concerns). If you need a fix-width layout, you would be _very_ well advised to adopt a table layout that is HTML email friendly.

Comment: Thanks so much @zeantsoi. This will probably do the trick for what I need. Can you tell me though how I can get the "subscribe" text to be centered in the button? It dropped lower - http://screencast.com/t/bLOQXv1svTB

Comment: Try applying the line-height attribute to the submit button: `<input style="width: 15%; float: right; margin-top: -32px; display: block; line-height: 17px;" type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">`. jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3kfuC/

Comment: @JeffEvans, did that resolve the issue? If so, it would be both polite and helpful to accept this answer as correct: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button pull-right">
```

Class "pull-right" belong to Bootstrap.

Comment: If this is going in a html email this wouldnt work because you cant pull in external stylesheets and style tags dont work cross client. Check out this link for more info -> http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1935/a-guide-to-css-support-in-emai

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:Why Dont you use simple css id selector to position your button.
Method 2:use webkit box to align horizontally your button.
Method 3:you can also make a table with 0 border to position your button.